# How to get a random datetime in a rake populate task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, rake, populate, auto-populate

```
  User.all.each do |user|
    7.times do
      user.schedules.create!(:user_id => user.id, :start_time => Time.now, :length => 25)
    end
  end
```

How can I replace the Time.now with a Time.random method? I found [this](http://jroller.com/obie/entry/random_times_for_rails) to help with getting random datetimes, but how can I use this method in a Rake task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you cite reopens the Time class and add the random method.  So, while I wouldn't advocate doing it you can just add the

```
class Time       
   def self.random(params={})
      ...
   end

end
```

directly to your rake file.  Another approach would be to add this code to a file in your lib directory - 'monkey_patch_time.rb', and then add

```
require 'monkey_patch_time'
```

to the top of your rake file.  I like this approach better, as it lets you use this method in other places.  Additionally, I like to collect all my monkey patches in a central location.